# Simple calculus question

Tags: calculus

Definition: $\Delta f(x) = f(x + \Delta x) - f(x)$. Find $\Delta^nf(x)$. My guess is

$$\Delta^nf(x)
 = f(x + n\Delta x) + \sum_{k=0}^{n}(-1)^kkf(x + (n-k)\Delta x) + (-1)^nf(x)$$

Is this guess correct?

Comment: Did you mean $\,\Delta^n f(x)\,$?

Comment: You may want to check N-th finite difference formula in: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_difference

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Calculate the first few values:

$$\begin{align*}
\Delta^2f(x)&=\Delta\left(f(x+\Delta x)-f(x)\right)\\
&=\Big(f(x+2\Delta x)-f(x+\Delta x)\Big)-\Big(f(x+\Delta x)-f(x)\Big)\\
&=f(x+2\Delta x)-2f(x+\Delta x)+f(x)\;,
\end{align*}$$

$$\begin{align*}
\Delta^3f(x)&=\Delta\left(\Delta^2f(x)\right)\\
&=\Delta\Big(f(x+2\Delta x)-2f(x+\Delta x)+f(x)\Big)\\
&=\Big(f(x+3\Delta x)-2f(x+2\Delta x)+f(x+\Delta x)\Big)\\
&\qquad\quad-\Big(f(x+2\Delta x)-2f(x+\Delta x)+f(x)\Big)\\
&=f(x+3\Delta x)-3f(x+2\Delta x)+3f(x+\Delta x)-f(x)\;,
\end{align*}$$

and

$$\begin{align*}
\Delta^4f(x)&=\Delta\left(\Delta^3f(x)\right)\\
&=\Delta\Big(f(x+3\Delta x)-3f(x+2\Delta x)+3f(x+\Delta x)-f(x)\Big)\\
&=\Big(f(x+4\Delta x)-3f(x+3\Delta x)+3f(x+2\Delta x)-f(x+\Delta x)\Big)\\
&\qquad\quad-\Big(f(x+3\Delta x)-3f(x+2\Delta x)+3f(x+\Delta x)-f(x)\Big)\\
&=f(x+4\Delta x)-4f(x+3\Delta x)+6f(x+2\Delta x)-4f(x+\Delta x)+f(x)\;.
\end{align*}$$

Now look at those sequences of coefficients:

$$\begin{align*}
&1,-2,1\\
&1,-3,3,-1\\
&1,-4,6,-4,1
\end{align*}$$

1. Do they match your formula?
2. Are they familiar from some other context?

Answer (score 1):

Your formula gives $\Delta f(x) = f(x+\Delta x)-2 f(x)$, so it can't be right.
Try computing the formula for $\Delta^2 f, \Delta^3 f$ and see if you can spot the pattern. Then verify by induction.

Here is the correct formula:

> $$\Delta^n f(x) = \sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^k \binom{n}{k} f(x+(n-k)\Delta x)$$

Comment: Did something change? I don't care about the points, but why did you 'unaccept' after two years?